# Copy nested objects from one XmlDocument to another

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-serialization, xml-parsing

I am at my wits end on this one. Here's the document I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Property1>TestObjectVal1</Property1>
  <Property2>TestObjectVal2</Property2>
  <Property3>TestObjectVal3</Property3>
  <SubObject>
    <Prop1>TestObject2Val1</Prop1>
    <Prop2>TestObject2Val2</Prop2>
    <Prop3>TestObject2Val3</Prop3>
  </SubObject>
</TestObject>
```

I'm trying to copy select portions of it to an new XmlDocument object based on some specified XPaths. I've tried every permutation I can think of. Here's where I'm at now.

```
var filters = new[] { "Property1", "Property2", "SubObject/Prop1" };

var xmlDoc = GetObjectXml(obj); //Loads the document
var newDoc = (XmlDocument)xmlDoc.Clone();
newDoc.DocumentElement.RemoveAll(); 
var rootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    var nodes = rootNode.SelectNodes(filter);
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        var newNode = newDoc.ImportNode(node, true);
        newDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode);
    }
}
```

What I'm getting back is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestObject>
  <Property1>TestObjectVal1</Property1>
  <Property2>TestObjectVal2</Property2>
  <Prop1>TestObject2Val1</Prop1>
</TestObject>
```

But I want this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Property1>TestObjectVal1</Property1>
  <Property2>TestObjectVal2</Property2>
  <SubObject>
    <Prop1>TestObject2Val1</Prop1>
  </SubObject>
</TestObject>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that the xpath method is selecting the inner element, so that the *SubObject" information is getting lost.  This code should result in the correct output for your specific example.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    XmlElement newNode; 
    string[] xpathElements = filter.Split('/');
    if (xpathElement.Length == 2) 
    {
        newNode = newDoc.CreateElement(filter);
        newNode.AppendChild(newDoc.ImportNode(node, true));

    }
    else 
    {
        newNode = newDoc.ImportNode(node, true);
    }
    newDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode);
}
```

Note that this code makes restrictive assumptions about what form the "filter" xpath expression must take... namely, it must be of the form "RootElement" or "RootElement/ChildElement" (no attributes an max depth of three).  That might be enough depending on your use case, but solving for more general cases would be a bit more tricky ...